# Is it possible to turn off the device (iPhone/iPad) from with in the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to make an app that has a type of parental control where the parent selects a specific time during the day, which when reached, will shut off the device completely. Then if the device is immediately turned on again it will display a pin-code to enter.

If no such function exists then is there anything that can be done related to this matter at all?

Comment: Of course it is impossible

Comment: @AndreyChernukha: Why "of course"? Obviously, there is a way since Apple is using it. But there's no way for us 3rd party devs on non-jailbroken systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such functionality. There might be a way on jailbroken devices, but in the official SDK there is no way to shut down the system.

Even if there were, the user could immediately turn the device back on. Your app wouldn't be running and thus the device would not shut down again, so your mechanism is easily sidestepped.

Comment: Mhm, you're right. I thought that's probably the only reasonable outcome but wanted to make sure in case someone had deeper knowledge of this. Thank you.